# How can loop & get values of unlimited parent-child & sub-child tree data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have data like parent-child with unlimited levels of sub-child & sub-child data in the database which you can see below like a binary tree with nodes that have multiple children and these children can have unlimited sub-child.

Please give me a solution or suggestion how can show that. Thanks.

This is my database JSON data which I'm getting from the database...

Controller Code

```
$products = Product::where('project_id', $project_id )->whereNull('parent_id')->with('categories')->with('childProducts')->get();
```

Getting data from the above object this data want to save in the other way you can see below

```
{
    "data": {
        "products": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "ParentProduct",
            "project_id": 1,
            "parent_id": null,
            "created_by": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
            "categories": [{
                "id": 6,
                "product_id": 1,
                "project_id": 1,
                "name": "TopLevelCategory",
                "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
            }],
            "child_products": [{
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "LevelOneProduct",
                    "project_id": null,
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "created_by": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                    "categories": [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "product_id": 2,
                        "project_id": 1,
                        "name": "LevelOneProductCategory",
                        "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                        "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
                    }],
                    "child_products": [{
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "LevelOneProductChildFolder",
                        "project_id": null,
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "created_by": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                        "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                        "categories": [{
                            "id": 2,
                            "product_id": 3,
                            "project_id": 1,
                            "name": "evelOneProductChildFolderCategory",
                            "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
                        }],
                        "child_products": [{
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "LevelOneProductSubChildFolder",
                            "project_id": null,
                            "parent_id": 3,
                            "created_by": null,
                            "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "categories": [{
                                "id": 3,
                                "product_id": 4,
                                "project_id": 1,
                                "name": "LevelOneProductSubChildFolderCategory",
                                "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                                "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
                            }],
                            "child_products": []
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "LeveTwoProduct",
                    "project_id": null,
                    "parent_id": 1,
                    "created_by": null,
                    "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                    "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                    "categories": [],
                    "child_products": [{
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "LeveTwoProductFolder",
                        "project_id": null,
                        "parent_id": 5,
                        "created_by": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                        "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                        "categories": [{
                            "id": 4,
                            "product_id": 6,
                            "project_id": 1,
                            "name": "LeveTwoProductFolderCategory",
                            "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
                        }],
                        "child_products": [{
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "LeveTwoProductChildFolder",
                            "project_id": null,
                            "parent_id": 6,
                            "created_by": null,
                            "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                            "categories": [{
                                "id": 5,
                                "product_id": 7,
                                "project_id": 1,
                                "name": "LeveTwoProductChildFolderCategory",
                                "created_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00",
                                "updated_at": "2021-08-06 13:18:00"
                            }],
                            "child_products": []
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

I want to take this data to another JSON data which I have to give you an example as mentioned below I want to loop the above JSON data and want to make their need JSON with this data as like Dear Problem is that How can loop above data and can give to the other JSON keys you can see below. I want all data with loop and want to get all values and want equal all values to the keys as below

```
foreach ($products as $product) {   
    foreach ($product->categories as $singleCaegory) {                       
        $singleCaegoryData = [
            "name" => $singleCaegory->name, 
            "request" => [ 
                'method' =>  $singleCaegory->type,
                'body' => [
                    "mode" => "raw",
                    'raw' => $singleCaegory->raw_data
                ],
                'url' =>  [
                    "raw" =>  $singleCaegory->url
                ], 
            ],
        ]; 
    }
}
```

I think you understand my problem. that I want to loop above data which I have already in the database and fetching from that. I only want to loop all data and equal to the needed keys. Thanks.

Comment: Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257892/laravel-sub-categories-display-under-main-categories/54386915#54386915

Comment: Thanks, Dear @A.ANoman for replying to me. but this link is not helping me I have unlimited nested categories on different levels as you can see in my database result which I'm saving and fetching. I have mentioned above. I want to save this result in the database for some reason

Answer (score 0):

for saving Id's you only need:-parent Id, child_Id_count(count of the only direct child), total_child_count(count all children below).that's it by using these data and created date you can generate a tree view.

Comment: Thanks, Dear @ankit for replying to me. Please can you give me an example?

Comment: example for which one - tree view or to insert new id

Comment: try this example
https://www.truecodex.com/course/core-php/get-category-and-subcategory-in-php

Comment: any queries ask again !

Comment: https://www.codecheef.org/article/hierarchical-treeview-category-example-in-laravel
the link above has an example in laravel  if you want to change the view add then ask the designer to create a static page then you just have to add those html things inside your foreach loop

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dear @ankit that you are helping me.

Comment: I want to explain to you so that you could understand of my problem

Comment: Dear, I have saved this data which I have mentioned above JSON & fetching from database which is giving as like above. I want to loop this all data and get values so that could equal the other keys in the controller. Basically, I'm making another JSON data for import to another. My problem is that not looping parents & nested all child sub-child and not getting data so that I could equal to the keys which I have added an example in my question you can see. Thanks