# How to get the count of category highest level in a hierarchy?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a category table that have structure like

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first category | null |
| 2 | child | 1 |

which lets us to store category in a hierarchical level infinitely.
Now the thing i want to achieve is to get the count of highest level.
for example
[image: category level]

As shown in the picture
category KFC has 2 main children (first second child category and first child category)
from this two i want count of highest level . first second child category has more child than first child category so the answer i am expecting is 5 including the count of KFC (parent category) as well.
This is the code i have tried so far.

```
public function getCategoryLevel($category)
    {
        $count = [];
        if ($category->childs()->count()) {
            $count[] = 1;
            $this->recursiveLevel($category, $count, 2);
        }
        dd($count);
    }

    public function recursiveLevel($item, &$count, $append)
    {
        foreach ($item->childs as $key=>$i) {
            
                $count[] = $append;
                if ($i->childs()->count()) {
                    $append += 1;
                    $this->recursiveLevel($i, $count, $append);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can actually do this in raw SQL with a [recursive query](https://cjhaas.com/2019/10/25/mysql-recursive-cte/)

Comment: You might be interested in this solution (faster process) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685547/how-can-show-unlimited-parent-child-sub-child-tree-data-in-laravel/68685829#68685829 each child and subchild have the root parent id in a seperate field